# Make Excel CTRL+TAB work like Windows ALT+TAB

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

You can use CTRL+TAB to cycle through all open workbooks in Excel.  However, after releasing CTRL+TAB and then using CTRL+TAB again, I naturally expect it to cycle back to the previous workbook much in the way ALT+TAB works in Windows.  Instead, it just cycles to the next workbook.  To go back to the previous workbook, you have to use SHIFT+CTRL+TAB which is quite unwieldly.

Is there a way to get CTRL+TAB to cycle through workbooks like ALT+TAB cycles through applications in Windows?

Comment: No, Alt-Tab in windows cycles through last open apps, In Excel it will just cycle through in set order

Comment: If you are truly frustrated with Cycling simply install the Office Tab.